# Typescript Lambda Property is not a function

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and I am trying to use someone else's [plugin](https://github.com/HVND/ng-noty). [I have reached](https://github.com/HVND/ng-noty/issues/2) out to them for assistance, but I am not sure how long it might take. The repo hasn't been updated in over a year.

I am trying to create a NotyButton that is defined as:

```
interface NotyButton {
new(text: string, 
    classNames: string, 
    cb: Function, 
    attributes: any): NotyButton
}
```

The NotyButton is used within the NotyOptions:

```
export interface NotyOptions {
type?: NotyType;
layout?: NotyLayout;
theme?: NotyTheme;
text?: string;
timeout?: false | number;
progressBar?: boolean;
closeWith?: ('click' | 'button')[];
animation?: {
    open?: string | null | Function,
    close?: string | null | Function
};
id?: false | string;
force?: boolean;
killer?: boolean | string;
queue?: string;
container?: false | string;
buttons?: NotyButton[],
callbacks?: {
    beforeShow?: () => void,
    onShow?: () => void,
    afterShow?: () => void,
    onClose?: () => void,
    afterClose?: () => void,
    onHover?: () => void,
    onTemplate?: () => void
};
sounds?: {
    sources?: string[],
    volume?: number,
    conditions?: string[]
};
docTitle?: {
    conditions?: string[]
};
modal?: boolean,
}
```

There is a static method in the NotyModel class that exposes a button property that uses a lambda expression to return a NotyButton (if I am reading it correctly). I believe this is where my problem lies.

```
class NotyModel {
    static button: (text: string, classNames: string, cb: Function, attributes?: any) => NotyButton;
}
```

I have to use the NotyOptions object as a parameter in the create method of the NgNoty class:

```
declare let Noty: any;

@Injectable()
export class NgNoty {

create(options: NotyOptions): NotyModel {
    return new Noty(options);
}

closeAll(name?: string) {
    Noty.closeAll(name);
}

setMaxVisible(count: number, name?: string) {
    Noty.setMaxVisible(count, name);
}
}
```

I have a component create that is trying to use the create method of NgNoty like this:

```
    this.noty.create(<NotyOptions>{
    text: 'Problems Encountered',
    layout: 'bottomRight',
    theme: 'bootstrap-v4',
    type: 'error',
    buttons: [ 
      NotyModel.button('Ok', 'btn', () => {}, null)
    ]
}).show();
```

When I use NotyModel.button, I am getting **NotyModel.button is not a function**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the author of ng-noty may have forgotten to implement `NotyModel.button`.  I tried to implement it in [this fork](https://github.com/mattmccutchen/ng-noty/tree/issue-2), but I'm not familiar with how to test it.  Try it and if it works for you, one of us can submit a pull request.  (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51659332) for my preferred technique to add a locally modified version of an npm package to your application.)

Comment: Sorry. My attention has been moved else where for the day. I'll try to implement this as soon as I get back over.

Comment: That did the trick. Apparently, I have a lot more to learn about TypeScript syntax.