# Redux TS Generic type 'Dispatch<S>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Trying to setup a project with typescript and redux.
I am getting this error

```
Generic type 'Dispatch<S>' requires 1 type argument(s).
```

here is my `store.ts`

```
import { connectRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router'
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk'

import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

import reducers from './reducers'

import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

export const history = createBrowserHistory()

const composeEnhancers = composeWithDevTools({
  // Specify name here, actionsBlacklist, actionsCreators and other options if needed
})

const logger = createLogger()

const middleware = [ReduxThunk, logger]

const Store = createStore(connectRouter(history)(reducers), {}, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware, routerMiddleware(history))))

export default Store
```

here is root reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { ActionType } from 'typesafe-actions'

import * as actions from '../actions'

export interface IState {
   test: string
}

export type Actions = ActionType<typeof actions>

export default combineReducers<IState, Actions>({
  test: () => 'hey'
})
```

and here are some dummy actions

```
import { action } from 'typesafe-actions'

export const toggle = (id: string) => action('TOGGLE', id)
// (id: string) => { type: 'todos/TOGGLE'; payload: string; }
```

finally here is index.ts

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './App'
import './index.scss'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

import store, { history } from './store'

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router' // react-router v4
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}> { /* place ConnectedRouter under Provider */}
      <div> { /* your usual react-router v4 routing */}
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<div>Match</div>)} />
          <Route render={() => (<div>Miss</div>)} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
)
registerServiceWorker()
```

Here seems to be a similar issue without solution yet 
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/9611

But I am new to typescript so might be missing something basic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you are indeed facing the same issue you linked.  While we wait and see if 7mllm7's pull request is merged, you can use his modified version of the react-redux types.  I'd recommend the following approach:

1. `git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/7mllm7/DefinitelyTyped`
2. Copy the `types/react-redux` folder into your project (suppose for example you copy it to a folder named `react-redux.fixed`).
3. Edit `react-redux.fixed/package.json` to replace `"private": "true"` with `"name": "@types/react-redux"`.
4. In your `package.json`, specify the version of `@types/react-redux` as `./react-redux.fixed`.
5. Run `npm install`.  npm will make a symlink from `node_modules/@types/react-redux` to `react-redux.fixed`.

Compared to just editing the file in `node_modules/@types/react-redux`, this way npm knows you are using a modified version of the package and won't overwrite it.  (This process deserves to be widely known; I'll find a better place to document it if I have time.)

Comment: I followed as you said, and here is what I get now
`/home/hayk/projects/elboil/app/react-redux.fixed/react-redux-tests.tsx
(1,21): 'ReactElement' is declared but its value is never read.`

Comment: Try deleting the `react-redux-tests.tsx` file or excluding the `react-redux.fixed` folder in your `tsconfig.json` (the `index.d.ts` should still be pulled in by your imports).  This is one glitch with copying a types directory directly from DefinitelyTyped rather than using the built npm packages.

Comment: Yeah that fixed this one error but still throws another error `/home/hayk/projects/elboil/app/react-redux.fixed/v5/index.d.ts
(29,35): Type 'S' does not satisfy the constraint 'Action<any>'.`

Comment: Yes, the `v5` folder needs to be excluded or deleted too; it has an incompatible previous version of the react-redux types.  Hopefully that fixes all the errors.

Comment: Did everything advised above; problem persisted; capitulated and used `dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by downgrading to `Redux 3.7`. It has proper typings (There still aren't typings for `Redux 4.0`). There are some Github issues where they discuss about it ([here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/9611#issuecomment-419677361) and [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/27724#issuecomment-419677019)).