# Refs is empty object {} when using correct reference pattern in React with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

**PROBLEM:**

I'm trying to make an example from `react-cropper` work in TypeScript. The example works fine with .JSX and there are Typings for it, so I thought it would just work sublime, with some changes to the .JSX code.

One of the tricky things to get my head around was the reference pattern in TypeScript and React. However, I found this amazing **[question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33796267/how-to-use-refs-in-react-with-typescript)** which I've followed to set everything up.

**EXPECTED:**

That the ref-pattern would work as intended and I'd have access to the underlying functions (from the object).

I.e. I'm expecting to see that `this.cropRef` has access to `getCroppedCanvas` (defined in `react-cropper`).

**ACTUAL:**

`console.log(this)` in the `cropImage()` function shows that `refs` are empty, even though I'm following the above example.

Trying to use the now deprecated ref-pattern of using strings show me that `this` has the reference heading into the `cropImage()` function. However, because TS is strongly typed, I dont' have access to `getCroppedCanvas()`.

**CODE:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import Cropper from 'react-cropper';
import 'cropperjs/dist/cropper.css';

export class ImageEditor extends React.Component<any, any> {
    private cropRef : React.RefObject<Cropper>;

    constructor(props : any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            src : "",
            cropResult : ""
        };

        this.cropRef = React.createRef();  
        this.cropImage = this.cropImage.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(e : any) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let files;
        if (e.dataTransfer) {
            files = e.dataTransfer.files;
        } else if (e.target) { 
            files = e.target.files;
        }
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            this.setState({ src : reader.result });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    }

    cropImage() {
        console.log(this.refs);
        if (typeof this.cropRef.current.getCroppedCanvas() === 'undefined') {
                return;
        }
        this.setState({
            cropResult: this.cropRef.current.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL(),
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                    <input type="file" onChange={this.onChange} />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <Cropper
                        style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}
                        aspectRatio={16 / 9}
                        preview=".img-preview"
                        guides={false}
                        src={this.state.src} 
                        ref={(cropper : any) => { this.cropRef = cropper}}
                    />
                </div>
                    <div>
                        <div className="box" style={{ width: '50%', float: 'right' }}>
                            <h1>Preview</h1>
                            <div className="img-preview" style={{ width: '100%', float: 'left', height: 300 }} />
                        </div>
                    <div className="box" style={{ width: '50%', float: 'right' }}>
                        <h1>
                        <span>Crop</span>
                        <button onClick={this.cropImage} style={{ float: 'right' }}>
                            Crop Image
                        </button>
                        </h1>
                        <img style={{ width: '100%' }} src={this.state.cropResult} alt="cropped image" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

edited index.d.ts for ***react-cropper***:

```
import * as cropperjs from 'cropperjs';
import * as React from 'react';

import Data = cropperjs.Data;
import ContainerData = cropperjs.ContainerData;
import ImageData = cropperjs.ImageData;
import CanvasData = cropperjs.CanvasData;
import CropBoxData = cropperjs.CropBoxData;
import CroppedCanvasOptions = cropperjs.CroppedCanvasOptions;
type ReactCropperProps = cropperjs.CropperOptions & React.AllHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>;

interface ReactCropper extends cropperjs {} // tslint:disable-line no-empty-interface
declare class ReactCropper extends React.Component<ReactCropperProps> {
    on(eventname: string, callback: () => void): void;
}
export default ReactCropper;
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "packages for content",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "karma start karma.unit.build.js",
    "build-test": "karma start karma.unit.js",
    "coverage": "karma start karma.coverage.js"
  },
  "author": "Joakim Bajoul Kakaei",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.4",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.5",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.7",
    "@types/react-cropper": "./node_modules/react-cropper.fixed",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.6",
    "@types/react-dropzone": "^4.2.0",
    "@types/sinon": "^5.0.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.5",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.5",
    "karma-typescript-preprocessor2": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "mocha-webpack": "^1.1.0",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.16",
    "sinon": "^6.1.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "npm": "^6.3.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-cropper": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.2.13"
  }
}
```

node_modules/react-cropper/package.json:

```
{
    "name": "@types/react-cropper",
    "dependencies": {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a strange mix of the callback pattern and the `RefObject` pattern.  If you want to use the `RefObject`, you should just pass the `RefObject` as the `ref` attribute, i.e.:

```
ref={this.cropRef}
```

If you want to use a callback, then the declaration should be:

```
private cropRef : Cropper;
```

and you would use `this.cropRef.getCroppedCanvas()` rather than `this.cropRef.current.getCroppedCanvas()`.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I'm getting errors basically EVERYWHERE when I do it just like that.
If I use the `RefObject` pattern, my code breaks on `this.cropRef.getCroppedCanvas()` because the method does not exist on the type `RefObject<Cropper>` and on my `ref` in the `Cropper` element. This because the `RefObject` is missing properties (such as `align`). This is a part of the error ```Type 'ReactCropper' is not assignable to type 'HTMLImageElement'. Property 'align' is missing in type 'ReactCropper'. ```

Comment: If you are using the `RefObject` pattern, then you should keep the `current` to dereference the `RefObject` in `this.cropRef.current.getCroppedCanvas()`.  Which way are you trying?

Comment: Using the `RefObject` pattern I'm using `current`, which solves the issue with having access go `getCroppedCanvas()`. However, I'm unable to set up the reference on the element

Comment: Did you use `ref={this.cropRef}`?  What error did you get?

Comment: Yeah. Part of the error can be seen on my first comment (last line).

Comment: Finally I actually tried this myself and it looks like there is a mistake in the type definition for `react-cropper`: `React.HTMLProps<HTMLImageElement>` should be replaced with `React.AllHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>`.  You can use [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51659332) to modify the type definition locally.

Comment: Motherclucker.... The time I've spent on trying to fix this myself and it's the type-definition files...
I might see if I can get a PR and sort that for anyone who comes next..

Comment: Ah. So I performed those changes, but now it says that this line is illegal:
```cropResult: this.cropRef.current.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL(),``` as `getCroppedCanvas()` does not exist on the `type 'ReactCropper'.`. Any clue?

Comment: You may have lost the `cropperjs` typings somehow.  If you jump to the definition of `Cropper`, you should see `interface ReactCropper extends cropperjs {}`.  If you then jump to the definition of `cropperjs`, what do you get?  Do you have `@types/cropperjs/index.d.ts` in your `node_modules`?  You could try adding `@types/cropperjs` to your `package.json`, though that shouldn't be necessary if you added the local `@types/react-cropper` in the way I suggested.

Comment: Looking at `Cropper` in the type definition shows me the `index.d.ts` file. Peeking at `interface ReactCropper extends cropperjs {}` refers to `node_modules\react-cropper.fixed`. So basically it seems as if the type definition refers to a type definition. Is that a circular dependency of some sort, then?
I'll add my package.json file in an edit

Comment: Ah, it looks like you need to add `"@types/cropperjs": "*"` to the dependencies of your `react-cropper.fixed/package.json` file.  This is another thing I wasn't aware of that the types-publisher normally takes care of, but people need to do manually when forking packages directly from DefinitelyTyped. :(

Comment: Yeah, that's a bit interesting. Especially since the type-definition's folder was missing a `package.json` file. So I just copied one from another type-definition. No wonder it didn't work as intended...