# How to use getFormInitialValues selector with TypeScript properly?

Tags: typescript, redux-form

Found this solution, but I think this is a hack:

```
export const getInitialValues = getFormInitialValues('formName') as (state: State) => FormValues;
```

What is proper solution for using `getFormInitialValues` with TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [type declaration for `getFormInitialValues`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/00f8143ceb154ce25a22ec338678f0520d2a2f3c/types/redux-form/lib/selectors.d.ts#L10):

```
export const getFormInitialValues: DataSelector;
```

where:

```
export type DataSelector<FormData = {}, State = {}> = (formName: string, getFormState?: GetFormState) => (state: State) => FormData;
```

It looks like `DataSelector` was probably intended to be a generic function type, so you could call it like `getFormInitialValues<FormValues, State>('formName')`, but was instead defined as a generic type alias where the type arguments are set to their default values.  The correct definition would be:

```
export type DataSelector = <FormData = {}, State = {}>(formName: string, getFormState?: GetFormState) => (state: State) => FormData;
```

I see the mistake was introduced in [this PR](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/18168).  Consider submitting a PR to correct all of the type aliases in the file.  In the meantime, you can add a copy of the typings to your project, modify them, and register them in `package.json` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51659332).